# How can I know that database indices are ok?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

On Microsoft SQL Server 2008 how can I know or find out that database indices are regenerated?

Answer (score 3):

The indexes are always maintained and consistent, unless an index is set to Disabled, in which case it will be unavailable for use until it is rebuilt.

You can use "DBCC CHECKTABLE table_name, indexid" to run an integrity check on a specific index.